# Firebase Real-time Database: Why I cannot import multiple JSON files in same directory hierarchy?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to import my JSON files into the same directory but once I import the first one, the latter one overrides the former one:

The first import:

[image: ss1]

After the second one:

[image]

As you can see above, the first file was placed inside the latter one. How can I import multiple JSON files in the same directory level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you import the data using the console, any data in the JSON file replaces the existing location where you run the import. There is no way to change this behavior.

What you **can** do is import the data to a different location in the console. So if you open the `recipes` node to import the first JSON, and open the `searches` node for the second JSON, the two imports won't overwrite each other.

If you want to import them into the root of the database, you'll have to merge the two JSON files yourself and then import them in one go.

Comment: I created two child nodes under the root of the database, it is okay in this way but it seemed weird to me. Why they designed the system in this way, just weird. Anyway, if this is the only way, there is nothing to do. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You probably just had the wrong one node selected when running the import, as the screenshot suggests.

Comment: @MartinZeitler No, whatever I choose, it was importing in this way. I don't know why.

Comment: @bbasaran Most likely because the node to import to didn't exist yet.

Comment: Good one Martin! In that case you can type it in the URL that the explorer shows, but that's definitely easy to overlook.